# mocking global variables on python doesn't work

Tags: python, mocking

I am trying to mock global variable using mock engine, but it seems that it doesn't simply work for my variables. When I patch for example `os.name` it works perfectly fine, however for my custom variables it doesn't work.
Here is the code:

**global_var.py**

```
var = 10
```

**use_global_var.py**

```
from global_var import var


def test_call():
    return var
```

**test.py**

```
import mock

from use_global_var import test_call


@mock.patch('global_var.var', 50)
def test_check():
    print(test_call())

test_check()
```

`print` is supposed to return 50 if I understand it right, but it returns 10.
Does anybody know what is the problem here and how to solve it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You aren't mocking the right *name*. `use_global_var.test_call` is looking at the name `use_global_var.var`, but you are mocking `global_var.var`.

```
@mock.patch('use_global_var.var', 50)
def test_check():
    print(test_call())

test_check()
```

Comment: ahh, it imports and becomes use_global_var.var.. that sounds right. thanks very much for quick answer.

Comment: Right; if you had simply used `import global_var` and `return global_var.var`, then `'global_var.var'` would be the right thing to patch.

Comment: it's weird :) probably clean enough for someone from a python world, but not for the others.

Comment: If the variable is used in let's say 4 different places and imported like in my example above then I have to patch all of them.

Comment: Remember that a Python variable is always just a name (and not necessarily a unique one) that references an otherwise anonymous object. Mocking (as defined by the `mock` library, anyway) is just the practice of changing what one particular name refers to; it does not replace an object in memory with a different object.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!